# seperate distict values from a list into different list object c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list object where I have 100 numbers.
I want to separate all list object with respect to all unique numbers.

Here is my list object

```
public class USERDETAILS
{
     private long _ID;
     public long ID
     {
         get { return _ID; }
         set { _ID = value; }
     }

     private long _MSISDN;
     public long MSISDN
     {
         get { return _MSISDN; }
         set { _MSISDN = value; }
     }
}

List<USERDETAILS> lstUSERDETAILS = new List<USERDETAILS>();
```

I have 10 numbers in my list

```
ID  MSISDN
101 9000001
102 9000002
103 9000002
104 9000003
105 9000003
106 9000003
107 9000007
108 9000008
109 9000009
110 9000010
```

I want to get duplicated entries in different list objects.
Here's expected output:

1st list object:

```
ID  MSISDN
101 9000001
102 9000002
104 9000003
107 9000007
108 9000008
109 9000009
110 9000010
```

2nd list object:

```
ID  MSISDN
103 9000002
105 9000003
```

3rd list object:

```
ID  MSISDN
106 9000003
```

I have tried with linq group by ;

```
var listOfUnique_USERDETAILS_Lists = listUSERDETAILS.GroupBy(p => p.MSISDN).Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Also I had tried iterating it over for loop to get distinct numbers and then putting up it in `list<USERDETAILS>` object and then creating  it in new list of duplicated entries but want to do it with more simplified way.

Comment: And what have you tried to do so far to solve this problem?  What issues have you had with your attempted implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

If you run this:

```
List<UserDetails> source = new List<UserDetails>();

UserDetails[][] grouping = source
                         .GroupBy( x=> x.MSISDN )
                         .Select( y => y.OrderBy( z => z.ID ).ToArray() )
                         .ToArray()
                         ;
```

gives you an array of `UserDetails[]`.

`grouping[n]` gives you the array of all the `UserDetails` objects sharing the same `MSISDN` value, ordered by their `ID` property.

`grouping[n][0]` will give you the first such object for that `MSISDN`. Iterating over that will give you the "distinctified" set of "first" objects. Since every grouping is guaranteeed to have at least one such item, we can simply say:

```
UserDetails[] firstList = grouping.Select( x => x.First() ).ToArray() ;
```

You can get your 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. lists by:

```
        int n = 2 ; // specify a suitable value for n such that n > 0 (1:1st, 2:2nd, etc.)
        UserDetails[] nthList = grouping.Select( x => x.Skip(n-1).FirstOrDefault() ).Where( x => x != null ).ToArray() ;
```

Note: since the 2d array is *jagged* (and so, every `MSISDN` may not have an *nth* element, we use `Skip(n-1).FirstOrDefault().Where( x => x != null )` to toss the missing items.

The more general solution would be to take the `grouping[][]` and *transpose its rows and columns, such that `grouping[x][y]` becomes `ranking[y][x]`. That lets you look at the transposed `ranking[][]` as having `ranking[0]` being the `UserDetails[]` that is your 1st-ranked objects across all `MSISDN` values, `ranking[0]` being your 2nd ranked objects across all `MSISDN` values, etc.

You you'll probably want to do something more than a simple transposition since any given `MSISDN` may not have an nth-ranked item, for any value of *n* larger than 0.

I believe (untested) that you can do the 2-D transposition something like this with LINQ:

```
UserDetails[][] ranking = Enumerable
                          .Range( 0 ,grouping.Max(x => x.Length) )
                          .Select( rank => Enumerable
                                           .Range(0,grouping.Length)
                                           .Select( msisdn => grouping[msisdn].Skip(rank-1).FirstOrDefault() )
                                           .Where( x => x != null )
                                           .ToArray()
                          )
                          .ToArray()
                          ;
```

At the end of which `ranking[0]` should be your first list, `ranking[1]` your second list and `ranking[2]` your third list.

Comment: Thank You So much!!! It worked perfect as I wanted!! 
In the 2-D transposition, Used `rank` instead of `rank-1` and it gave all the distinct list object!!!

Answer (score 0):

So first group the items, using `GroupBy`, then you can iterate over the groups and project them out to `IEnumerator` objects, pulling out the groups that still have items left and yielding the next item, until none of the groups have any items.

```
//TODO give better name
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Foo<T, TKey>(
    IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> selector)
{
    var groups = source.GroupBy(selector)
        .Select(group => group.GetEnumerator())
        .ToList();
    while (groups.Any())
    {
        yield return groups.Select(iterator => iterator.Current);
        groups = groups.Where(iterator => iterator.MoveNext())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```